# .contains not working with custom object

Tags: arrays, swift

I am using the below code to update my array. My requirement is that the new data does not exist, for that I am using the .contains method.

This method is not working properly when I change the viewcontroller and come again on same page. It returns `false` and I keep getting duplicate results due to that.

Is this an issue related to the custom object?

```
if let list  =  rooms as? [[String : AnyObject]]
{
    // self.roomList = [Room]()
    for item in list
    {
      let roomStr = json(from: item)
      let roomObj : Room = Room(JSONString: roomStr!)!
      if !self.roomList.contains(roomObj)
      {
        self.roomList.append(roomObj)
      }  
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      //First sort by name and then sort by default room..
      self.roomList.sort { $0.getRoomName()! < $1.getRoomName()! }
      self.roomList.sort { $0.getDefaultRoom()! && !$1.getDefaultRoom()! }
      self.LoadRoomsTableView.reloadData()
      self.hideActivity()
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve it or any suggest on the effiecient  way for add/update the data in array with swift.

Comment: Every time you create any instance of class it will create new instance and will have new address in the memory so it can not be same what you added in the array previously. So better to match with the object id instead of object itself. You should use `contains where` method.

Comment: Its a tab based App so the instance is exist and my array is not blank, the issue is related to duplicate data.

Comment: You're creating `roomObj` just before checking `contains` so it will not match with existing room's objects added in the `self.roomList`. Because this is different object and array contains the different one although both have same data but not the same object. Try matching with Id as I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: You are right, may be because of this i am getting true in contains, i have checked the object description it is different.

Comment: what do you suggest should i used  Equatable.

Comment: You can test it by printing the `roomList` array and `roomObj`, You will see the different memory address so that condition is not matching. Use `self.roomList.contains {$0.id == roomId}`

Comment: You can check the following [example code snippet](https://pastebin.com/dqrGt4s6).

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure your `Room` class/struct implements the protocol `Equatable`.

Example:

```
class Room {

    let rooms: Int
    let color: String

    init(rooms: Int, color: String) {
        self.rooms = rooms
        self.color = color
    }

}

extension Room: Equatable {
    func ==(lhs: Room, rhs: Room) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rooms == rhs.rooms &&  lhs.color == rhs.color
    }
}
```

If you had a `struct` and Swift > 4.1+ you would not have this problem, as the `==` is kindly provided by Swift. Thanks Vadian for the reminder.

Comment: In Swift 4.1+ the `==` function is synthesized.

Comment: Also in case of `class`? I have only found example for structs.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply let me check that.

Comment: You're right, but in a class you have to add also an initializer .

Comment: This answer is also helpful but the solution of @TheTiger in comment  is much better for my situation .

Comment: I don't understand why you create an object out of the `list` every time and don't just compare the elements of the `list`. It seems like an overkill. Also, if you are creating items out of a json, your best bet would be to make `Room` a struct and make it Codable. Swift offers synthesised solutions to convert from JSON. You would need not further code than that.